# How can I sort multi index created for bokeh vplot?

Tags: pandas, sorting, bar-chart, bokeh, pandas-groupby

I have a problem when dealing when bokeh vplots that need a groupby. The problem is that vplots need that **x_range** is composed by strings and, if I convert the columns (month, year) before df.groupby((code,year, month)), months 10, 11 and 12 will be placed just after 1.

```
group = df2.groupby(('Code' ,'Year', 'Month'))

source = ColumnDataSource(group)

index_cmap  = factor_cmap('Code_Year_Month', palette=['red', 'green', 
'navy'], factors=sorted(df2.Code.unique()),end=1)

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=300, title="Test",
    x_range=group, toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x='Code_Year_Month', top='Column_mean', width=1, source=source,
   line_color="white", fill_color=index_cmap, fill_alpha = 0.5)

p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("column:", "@column_mean"),\
                            ("Code: ", "@Code"),\
                            ("Year: ", "@Year"),\
                            ("Month: ", "@CMonth")]))
p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.05
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xaxis.axis_label = ".... X"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "...."
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.2
p.outline_line_color = None

grid = gridplot(p, ncols=1, plot_width=800, plot_height=300, sizing_mode= 
'stretch_both', toolbar_location = 'right')

show(grid)
```

Here is the ValueError when I try to use x_range when some columns are int o float.

```
ValueError: expected an element of either Seq(String), Seq(Tuple(String, String)) or Seq(Tuple(String, String, String)), got [('P42F', 2015, 7), ...
```

How can I sort multi index from:

```
group = df2.groupby(('Code' ,'Year', 'Month')
```

when all columns need to be strings?